# Blender 2.8 - I want to ALWAYS see the axis gizmo when moving an object

Tags: axis, gizmo

When I am moving an object in Object Mode, the axis gizmo disappears.  This is very unhelpful.  Is there a way to make it always visible?

I want to always see this gizmo:

[image]

Comment: Currently it's not possible to show the gizmo while dragging. The discussion related to (one of) the feature requests can be found [here](https://developer.blender.org/T63743) including the explanation by Julian Eisel what challenges exist for implementing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is a way.

Just click the gizmo, instead of dragging it.
Then use the pop-up menu to adjust the values, and the gizmo stays visible.

[image]

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you :)

Comment: Happy to help :).

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle on/off gizmos for move, rotation and scale here… 
To activate this first you need to select "Active object" - above those three…

When you're satisfied with interface changes (settting up gizmos, deleting standard cube etc) go to FILE => DEFAULT => SAVE START UP FILE. Next time you create a new file it will be the way you like it.

[image]

Comment: Question is: Is there a way the gizmo stays visible *while transforming* an object...?

Comment: This answer is very correct, I don't mind that OP asked something different, because I got into here by googling "blender object gizmos save". And that is what I want. Stupid downvoters begone!